# in drupal not able to over ride the css in page.tpl

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

Getting stuck while over riding style in node view (page.tpl )

[sample content](http://happylife.in/node/56)

in this page, trying to align the label txt_image1_desc: in the left and content should align right " **my image desc need to align**  "

i tried in page.tpl with css stuff, but not get align,

how to over ride page.tpl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS file:

```
.field-label {
  float:left;
}
```

That should render the output like this:  `txt_image1_desc: my image desc need to align`